# Auto height of outer div

Tags: html, css

i know this has been asked before an such, but i've tried like 5 different ways from Stack and 5 from other websites, and i can't seemsto find the right one.
It's a simple problem, the php_content div aren't getting bigger as it should be with content put into it.

```css
    /******************************************************
    / CSS RESET
    /*****************************************************/
    
    html,body,div,ul,ol,li,dl,dt,dd,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,p,blockquote,fieldset,input,hr {margin:0; padding:0;}
    h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,address,caption,cite,code,em,strong,th {font-size:1em; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal;}
    ul,ol {list-style:none;}
    fieldset,img,hr {border:none;}
    caption,th {text-align:left;}
    table {border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0;}
    td {vertical-align:top;}
    
    /*****************************************************/
    
    *{
        box-sizing: border-box;
    
        float: left;
    }
    
    .container{
        width: 1000px;
        height: 600px;
    }
    
    .code{
        float: left;
    
        width: 800px;
        height: 600px;
    
        background-color: #333333;
    
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .php{
        position: relative;
    
        top: 100px;
        left: 100px;
    }
    
    .php_start,
    .if_start{
        display: inline-block;
        clear: left;
    
        height: 15px;
        min-width: 100px;
    
        background-color: #CD8B32;
    
        border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 0;
    }
    
    .php_start span,
    .if_start span{
        margin-left: 20px;
    
        color: white;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    
    .php_content,
    .if_content{
        display: inline-block;
        clear: left;
    
        min-width: 100px;
        min-height: 50px;
    
        border-left: 10px solid #CD8B32;
    }
    
    .php_end,
    .if_end{
        display: inline-block;
        clear: left;
    
        height: 15px;
        min-width: 100px;
    
        background-color: #CD8B32;
    
        border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    }
    
    .code .if{
        position: absolute;
    }
    
    .toolbox{
        float: left;
    
        width: 200px;
        height: 600px;
    
        background-color: #333333;
    
        border-left: 2px solid lightgrey;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="code">
            <div class="php">
                <div class="php_start">
                    <span>PHP</span>
                </div>
                <div class="php_content">
                    <div class="if">
                        <div class="if_start">
                            <span>IF</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="if_content">
                            <div style="height: 100px;"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="if_end"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="php_end"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="toolbox">
            <div class="if">
                <div class="if_start">
                    <span>IF</span>
                </div>
                <div class="if_content">
    
                </div>
                <div class="if_end"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do...do you have an image of what this is supposed to look like. I have some concerns that **everything** is floated ledt and you seem to have an absolutely positioned object with no positioning values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `php_content` div contains a div that is absolutely positioned, which means `php_content` cannot match the size of its contents.

The fix is to remove this:

```
.code .if{
    position: absolute;
}
```

Live Example:

```css
/******************************************************
/ CSS RESET
/*****************************************************/

html,body,div,ul,ol,li,dl,dt,dd,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,p,blockquote,fieldset,input,hr {margin:0; padding:0;}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,address,caption,cite,code,em,strong,th {font-size:1em; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal;}
ul,ol {list-style:none;}
fieldset,img,hr {border:none;}
caption,th {text-align:left;}
table {border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0;}
td {vertical-align:top;}

/*****************************************************/

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;

    float: left;
}

.container{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 600px;
}

.code{
    float: left;

    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;

    background-color: #333333;

    font-weight: bold;
}

.php{
    position: relative;

    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}

.php_start,
.if_start{
    display: inline-block;
    clear: left;

    height: 15px;
    min-width: 100px;

    background-color: #CD8B32;

    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 0;
}

.php_start span,
.if_start span{
    margin-left: 20px;

    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.php_content,
.if_content{
    display: inline-block;
    clear: left;

    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 50px;

    border-left: 10px solid #CD8B32;
}

.php_end,
.if_end{
    display: inline-block;
    clear: left;

    height: 15px;
    min-width: 100px;

    background-color: #CD8B32;

    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
}

.toolbox{
    float: left;

    width: 200px;
    height: 600px;

    background-color: #333333;

    border-left: 2px solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="code">
        <div class="php">
            <div class="php_start">
                <span>PHP</span>
            </div>
            <div class="php_content">
                <div class="if">
                    <div class="if_start">
                        <span>IF</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="if_content">
                        <div style="height: 100px;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="if_end"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="php_end"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="toolbox">
        <div class="if">
            <div class="if_start">
                <span>IF</span>
            </div>
            <div class="if_content">

            </div>
            <div class="if_end"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, can't remember why i made this position, guess i used it for something in an earlier statement.

Answer (score 1):

```css
/******************************************************
    / CSS RESET
    /*****************************************************/
    
    html,body,div,ul,ol,li,dl,dt,dd,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,p,blockquote,fieldset,input,hr {margin:0; padding:0;}
    h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,address,caption,cite,code,em,strong,th {font-size:1em; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal;}
    ul,ol {list-style:none;}
    fieldset,img,hr {border:none;}
    caption,th {text-align:left;}
    table {border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0;}
    td {vertical-align:top;}
    
    /*****************************************************/
    
    *{
        box-sizing: border-box;
    
        float: left;
    }
    
    .container{
        width: 1000px;
        height: 600px;
    }
    
    .code{
        float: left;
    
        width: 800px;
        height: 600px;
    
        background-color: #333333;
    
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .php{
        position: relative;
    
        top: 100px;
        left: 100px;
    }
    
    .php_start,
    .if_start{
        display: inline-block;
        clear: left;
    
        height: 15px;
        min-width: 100px;
    
        background-color: #CD8B32;
    
        border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 0;
    }
    
    .php_start span,
    .if_start span{
        margin-left: 20px;
    
        color: white;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    
    .php_content,
    .if_content{
        display: inline-block;
        clear: left;
        height: auto !important;
        min-width: 100px;
        min-height: 50px;
    
        border-left: 10px solid #CD8B32;
    }
    
    .php_end,
    .if_end{
        display: inline-block;
        clear: left;
    
        height: 15px;
        min-width: 100px;
    
        background-color: #CD8B32;
    
        border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    }
    
    .code .if{
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .toolbox{
        float: left;
    
        width: 200px;
        height: 600px;
    
        background-color: #333333;
    
        border-left: 2px solid lightgrey;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="code">
            <div class="php">
                <div class="php_start">
                    <span>PHP</span>
                </div>
                <div class="php_content">
                    <div class="if">
                        <div class="if_start">
                            <span>IF</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="if_content">
                            <div style="height: 100px;"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="if_end"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="php_end"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="toolbox">
            <div class="if">
                <div class="if_start">
                    <span>IF</span>
                </div>
                <div class="if_content">
    
                </div>
                <div class="if_end"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Change `position: absolute` to `relative` in the `.code .if` block. This way the reference will be set to the div containing it.

Comment: Thanks, can't remember why i made this position, guess i used it for something in an earlier statement.